# AMD graphics Ubuntu driver issue

Tags: 16.04, amd-graphics

I'm trying to install the drivers for my AMD RX 460 graphics card but whenever I do so Ubuntu is rendered unbootable. I get an error saying

> the system is running in low-graphics mode

and whatever selection I make results in a black screen. Is this an issue with AMD's graphics card driver or am I doing something wrong? The graphics card works fine with windows. Luckily I dual boot.

Can I get the card working in Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes this is most likely a graphics card problem. I faced the same problem when I messed up the driver install process for my nvdia graphics card. You should still be able to boot into to the non-gui interface by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 during the boot process. I would recommend trying to remove everything related to AMD on your ubuntu install and then trying it again. Can you also give me some more information on how you went about the driver install process?

Comment: I followed the instructions on AMD's site here http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx I also uninstalled the driver using the same link. I tried installing the driver at least 3 times. I also did a sudo apt-get update and upgrade but also didn't work.

Comment: At this point, I would recommend just reinstalling ubuntu. You can use the tty console to take a backup and then install ubuntu from a live usb. btw there is an easier way to go about installing proprietary graphics card drivers. Just go to ubuntu software and updates in settings and there is a tab called additional drivers there. You just select your graphics card driver and click on ok. You can have a fresh ubuntu install up and running in a couple of hours, diagnosing this problem will take longer

Comment: I forgot to mention in the post that i did reinstall Ubuntu about  3 times and also tried going into the additional drivers section but it said i had no drivers available. At this point it would probably be worth just using integrated graphics for Ubuntu and the AMD graphics card for windows. I had nothing important on Ubuntu because i mapped my home folder to store everything on a 2TB HDD all i had on it was Google chrome, steam and virtualbox.

Comment: You can try out an older version. Maybe there is a problem in the newest version

Comment: Also, I do not know about amd drivers, but for the nVidia driver, I had to switch to the tty console and disable lightdm before installing it

Comment: I'll try to find an older version. Also AMD have a beta driver I'll try that as well.

Comment: I found the solution. In the bios i disabled the integrated graphics and onboard sound card. That seemed to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Luke Watson: You can actually [post your own solution as an answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer), but I've gone ahead and done so. You can still post an answer--you did find the solution, after all. If you do, I'll delete the answer I posted or keep it, depending on whether it seems like it's still useful in light of your own answer. You can also let us know if you think the question @Zanna suggested would solve this. *You don't have to do any of these things* if you don't want to--there is no further action you *need* to take here--I just want to make sure you know what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

The original poster figured out a solution and posted it in a comment:

> I found the solution. In the bios i disabled the integrated graphics
>   and onboard sound card. That seemed to have fixed the issue.

– [**Luke Watson**](https://askubuntu.com/users/680082/luke-watson) [Apr 21 at 11:50](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906684/amd-graphics-ubuntu-driver-issue#comment1425384_906684)